# Finding full skewed normal distribution PDF given three values on the curve.

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

Assuming [skewed normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skew_normal_distribution) and given value for the mean $\left(\xi+\omega\delta\sqrt{\dfrac2\pi}\right)$ and two points with identical density value.

$$y_1= PDF(x_1) \\ y_2= PDF(x_2) \\ y_1 = y_2$$

Is it possible to solve for the PDF?

Comment: Why $ξ+ωδ\sqrt{\dfrac2π}$? Why is it not enough to say that the mean is $m$?

Comment: Well the mean is skewed, you can name it m, but I wanted to make sure that I dont mean $ξ$

Comment: Doesn't it depend on how many parameters your skewed Normal pdf has? You have not defined $\omega$ or $\delta$. To illustrate the point, if $X \sim N(0,1)$ and $g(x)=2 f(x)F(\lambda x)$ has a skew-Normal pdf, and $\lambda$ is not known, but the mean of the skew-Normal $\frac{\sqrt{2} \lambda }{\sqrt{\pi  \lambda ^2+\pi }}$ is known, you can solve for $\lambda$, and uniquely find the pdf without even knowing $y_1$ or $y_2$.